# Как из php файла выполнить команду ssh и сохранить результат?

Tags: php, ssh

Необходимо xml преобразовать в json, нашел отлично работающий метод но с использованием ssh команды:

`php -f xml2json_test.php test2.xml`

Результатом выполнения является полностью валидный json.

**Можно как-то запускать подобную команду из php скрипта (планирую по крону) и сохранять результат в json файл или базу данных**?

Иначе не понятно, как для меня может быть полезна данная функция преобразования.

Спасибо!

Comment: Это не команда ssh. У ssh вообще нет команд. ssh это средство подключиться к консоли удаленной машины. У вас скрипты расположены на разных машинах ? Если на одной, то можно воспользоваться просто запуском программы https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.system.php Но учитывая что это то же php скрипт я бы его посмотрел, весь запуск внутри завернул бы в функцию, подключил include и вызывал бы функцию. Тем более что не все хостинги позволяют выполнять внешние программы

Comment: Здорово! Огромное спасибо за разъяснение, работает. Может ответом напишите, я приму как решение. Скрипты (xml2json) на одной машине.